# how to select and de-select an item in RecyclerView? How to Highlight selected item only in recycler view?

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview, background-color, selecteditem

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final mainscreenspecializationadap.MyViewHolder holder, final int positionz) {
        this.position = holder.getAdapterPosition();
        final specializationpojo album = albumList.get(holder.getAdapterPosition());
        holder.txtspecs.setText(album.getSplztnname());
        holder.imgspecs.setImageResource(album.getIcon());

    holder.linelayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            row_index=positionz;
            album.setOpened(!album.isOpened());
            notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    });
    if(positionz==row_index){
        holder.imageView.setBackground(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.white_circle_background));
        holder.txtspecs.setSelected(true);
        if (type==1)
        {
            onClick.onSelected(row_index,album.isOpened(),album.isClosed());
        }
        else if(type==2)
        {   onClick.onSpecialisationSelected(album.getSplzcode(),album.getCount());
        }
    }
    else
    {
        holder.txtspecs.setSelected(false);
        holder.imageView.setBackground(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.green_background));
    }

}
```

1. I have a recycler view where I need to select only one item, so on that basis, I have to show a sub list items.
2. Now the problem is when I unselect that item the below sub list items should be hidden.
3. Please suggest me an answer I will be thankful for the answer.

Answer (score 20):

Here is the solution for your requirement

```
    public class AdapterClass extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterClass.ViewHolder> {
        private int selected_position = -1;

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(AdapterClass.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
            if (selected_position == position) {
                // do your stuff here like
                //Change selected item background color and Show sub item views

            } else {
                  // do your stuff here like
                  //Change  unselected item background color and Hide sub item views
            }
  // rest of the code here

    holder.linelayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View view) {
              if(selected_position==position){
                        selected_position=-1;
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                        return;
                    }
                    selected_position = position;
                    notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        });

    //rest of the code here

     }


}
```

Comment: Among all of the others answers i could find, this one is trully working. Thanks !

Comment: I am glad it worked for you .You can ask me questions anytime . Happy coding

Comment: Really nice. Here's another of my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60905423/android-recyclerview-diffutils-animation-when-dataset-change-without-full-re) which is also about RecyclerView if you want to take a look !

Comment: Very elegant and effective.This should be marked as accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here, I solved this problem in an easy way.

I created 3 variables, singleSelectionItem, LastSelectedItemPosition, and LastSelectedItemState. With those variables, I wrote my recycler view adapter like this:

`

my code here:

```
var singleItemSelectionPosition = -1
var lastSelectedItemPosition = -1
var lastSelectedItemState = false
inner class ViewHolder(private val binding: ItemPatientsBinding) :
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    fun setContent(position: Int) {
        val patient = dif.currentList[adapterPosition]
        binding.apply {

            fullName.text = patient.full_name
            phoneNumber.text = patient.phone_number
            dateOfBirth.text = patient.date_of_birth
            addressTv.text = patient.address
            Log.d(TAG, "setContent: ${patient.full_name}")

            item.setOnClickListener {
                setSingleSelection(adapter position)
            }

            if (singleItemSelectionPosition == position) {

                if (lastSelectedItemPosition == singleItemSelectionPosition && lastSelectedItemState) {
                    lastSelectedItemState = false
                    checkBox.isChecked = false
                    onItemClick(-1)
                    itemCV.setCardBackgroundColor(binding.root.context.getColor(R.color.white))
                    Log.d(TAG, "setContent: Unselected")
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "setContent: selected")
                    checkBox.isChecked = true
                    onItemClick(patient.id)
                    itemCV.setCardBackgroundColor(binding.root.context.getColor(R.color.selected_item_color))
                    lastSelectedItemPosition = position
                    lastSelectedItemState = true
                }
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "setContent: last one unselected before new one selected")
                checkBox.isChecked = false
                itemCV.setCardBackgroundColor(binding.root.context.getColor(R.color.white))
            }

        }
    }
}

private fun setSingleSelection(adapterPosition: Int) {
    if (adapterPosition == RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) return
    notifyItemChanged(singleItemSelectionPosition)
    singleItemSelectionPosition = adapterPosition
    notifyItemChanged(singleItemSelectionPosition)
}
```

`

As you can see, I changed LastSelectedItemState after selecting true, and after selecting it, I changed it to false. It allows me to change the background color and in OnItemClick, I share the id of the selected item, if unselected happens, I share -1 in OnItemClick. It was a good solution to my problem. Single selection and unselecting in recycler view.