# How to properly DEselect an item on RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I followed this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/30046476/8793443
and got it to work: only one item is selected at a time (which is what I want).

However, when the same item is clicked for a second time, it remains selected. How can I deselect it so that it goes back to it's original color background?

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried using isSelected()?

Comment: Yes. Unfortunately, I haven't figured out how to make it work given the way it's done on the example from my link. That is, `notifyItemChanged(selectedPos)` is used twice (once with the previous position and then with the current position). However, when the same item is selected, `onBindViewHolder` only gets called once. How do you suggest using `isSelected()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The OnClick event must be this instead:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
  if (selectedPos == getAdapterPosition()) {
    selectedPos = RecyclerView.NO_POSITION;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
    return;
  }
  selectedPos = getAdapterPosition();
  notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

It works like a charm! Thanks to [Quick learner's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50872610) for inspiration.