# How to highlight clicked item in a RecyclerView while using ViewBinding?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewbinding

I've seen a type of answer for this in several posts but that doesn't seem to be working for me for some reason. Here's my code:

```
public class ScheduleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ScheduleAdapter.ScheduleViewHolder>
{
private Context context;
private ListitemScheduleBinding binding;
private Util util;
private List<TimeSlot> scheduleItems;
private ItemClickListener itemClickListener;
private int selectedPosition = RecyclerView.NO_POSITION;

public ScheduleAdapter(Context context, List<TimeSlot> scheduleItems)
{
    this.context = context;
    this.scheduleItems = scheduleItems;
    util = new Util();
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ScheduleViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
{
    binding = ListitemScheduleBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()), parent, false);
    return new ScheduleViewHolder(binding.getRoot());
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ScheduleViewHolder holder, int position)
{
    if (selectedPosition == position)
    {
        binding.cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
    }
    else
    {
        binding.cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
    }

    binding.cardView.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        if(selectedPosition == position)
        {
            selectedPosition = RecyclerView.NO_POSITION;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
            return;
        }

        selectedPosition = position;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    });

    TimeSlot scheduleItem = scheduleItems.get(position);

    String[] dateSplit = scheduleItem.getDate().split("-");
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, Integer.parseInt(dateSplit[0]));
    calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, (Integer.parseInt(dateSplit[1]) - 1));
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, Integer.parseInt(dateSplit[2]));

    binding.day.setText(util.getDayNameFromInt(calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)));
    binding.date.setText(String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%s %s", dateSplit[2], util.getMonthShortNameFromInt(calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH))));
    binding.slot.setText(scheduleItem.getTitle());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount()
{
    return scheduleItems.size();
}

public class ScheduleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener
{
    ScheduleViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView)
    {
        super(itemView);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view)
    {
        if (itemClickListener != null)
        {
            itemClickListener.onItemClick(view, getAdapterPosition());
        }
    }
}

public void setClickListener(ItemClickListener clickListener)
{
    this.itemClickListener = clickListener;
}

public interface ItemClickListener
{
    void onItemClick(View view, int position);
}
```

}

As can be see, I've implemented the answer mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50872380/how-to-select-and-de-select-an-item-in-recyclerview-how-to-highlight-selected-i) and in various other questions about this on stack.

However, when I click an item in my list, it either doesn't get highlighted, or another item gets highlighted instead of the one I clicked. Also sometimes, the content of the clicked item changes to that of another in the list.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try this --> holder.cardview.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));

Comment: @Wini color isn't the issue.

Answer (score 0):

`RecyclerView` does not handle item selection or states as a ListView does. Instead, you have to handle this manually in your view holder.

In your `ViewItemHolder constructor :

```
public ViewItemHolder(View holderItemView) {
        super(holderItemView);

        // Make this view clickable
        holderItemView.setClickable(true);

        // ...
    }
```

Comment: How will this help? The views are already clickable.

Answer (score 0):

The binding object had to be refreshed inside the ViewHolder class. Instead of using binding.view, use holder.binding.view. Declare binding inside the ViewHolder and assign it a value there.

Here's the working updated adapter:

```
public class ScheduleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ScheduleAdapter.ScheduleViewHolder>
{
private Util util;
private List<TimeSlot> scheduleItems;
private ItemClickListener itemClickListener;
private int lastClickedPosition = RecyclerView.NO_POSITION;

public ScheduleAdapter(List<TimeSlot> scheduleItems)
{
    this.scheduleItems = scheduleItems;
    util = new Util();
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ScheduleViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
{
    return new ScheduleViewHolder(ListitemScheduleBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()), parent, false));
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ScheduleViewHolder holder, int position)
{
    TimeSlot scheduleItem = scheduleItems.get(position);

    String[] dateSplit = scheduleItem.getDate().split("-");
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, Integer.parseInt(dateSplit[0]));
    calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, (Integer.parseInt(dateSplit[1]) - 1));
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, Integer.parseInt(dateSplit[2]));

    holder.binding.day.setText(util.getDayNameFromInt(calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)));
    holder.binding.date.setText(String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%s %s", dateSplit[2], util.getMonthShortNameFromInt(calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH))));
    holder.binding.slot.setText(scheduleItem.getTitle().replaceFirst(" ", "\n"));

    holder.itemView.setSelected(lastClickedPosition == position);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount()
{
    return scheduleItems.size();
}

public class ScheduleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener
{
    ListitemScheduleBinding binding;

    ScheduleViewHolder(@NonNull ListitemScheduleBinding binding)
    {
        super(binding.getRoot());
        this.binding = binding;
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view)
    {
        if (itemClickListener != null)
        {
            itemClickListener.onItemClick(view, getAdapterPosition());
        }

        notifyItemChanged(lastClickedPosition);
        lastClickedPosition = getLayoutPosition();
        notifyItemChanged(lastClickedPosition);
    }
}

public void setClickListener(ItemClickListener clickListener)
{
    this.itemClickListener = clickListener;
}

public interface ItemClickListener
{
    void onItemClick(View view, int position);
}
```

}